# Text Shadow with jquery

Tags: jquery

I wish to change the text-shadow attribute of elements with javascript. As far as I know jquery css does not work with text-shadow.

Does anyone have any suggestions for dynamically changing text-shadow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Works for me (Chrome and FF, not IE).

Try using camelCase. When working with CSS properties in JavaScript, you have to remove the hyphen (for example, "background-image" would become "backgroundImage") and then set the properties.

So your code should read:

> $('#bla').css('textShadow','#6374AB 20px -12px 2px');

Answer (score 0):

There is always this [this](http://kilianvalkhof.com/uploads/ieshadow.html) little script.

But I don't understand why this wouldn't work:

```
$('#bla').css('text-shadow','#6374AB 20px -12px 2px');
```

Edit: Well, I tried it, and indeed jQuery was not impressed with my attempts. But I did find another [script](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/f9df5396ea4dfcac).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#text").hover(function() { 
    $(this).animate({textShadow: "#aaa 6px 6px 6px"});
}, function() { 
    $(this).animate({textShadow: "#ccc 3px 3px 3px"});
});
```

This and more at Alex Peattie's website: 
http://alexpeattie.com/projects/animate-textshadow/

Answer (score 0):

You can also place it inside an object.

```
({"text-shadow" : "#6374AB 20px 12px 2px"})
```