# trying to set Text-Shadow property using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set text-shadow property by taking the values from user and changing it using JQuery..My code is as  follows

HTML Code

```
<td width="13%">
H-Shadow::<input id="hshadow" onchange="setShadow();"/>
</td>

<td width="13%">
V-Shadow::<input id="vshadow" onchange="setShadow();"/>
</td>

<td width="12%">
Blur::<input id="blur" onchange="setShadow();"/>
</td>

<td width="12%">
Color::<input id="shadowcolor" class="color" onchange="setShadow();"/>
</td>
```

My function setShadow is as follows

```
function setShadow() {
var horShadow = document.getElementById('hshadow');
var verShadow = document.getElementById('vshadow');
var blurShadow = document.getElementById('blur');
var colorShadow = document.getElementById('shadowcolor');
$('.blue3d > textarea').css('textShadow', horShadow.value+"px "+verShadow.value+"px "+blurShadow.value+"px "+'#'+colorshadow.color);
```

}

Also to the 4th  for selection color..i am using jscolor picker..So i needed to add class=color in 4th .. u can see the jscolor picker here [jsColor](http://jscolor.com/)

Where i am going wrong ?

Comment: Is it just my or this question has no question...? <------- Wait it has one now!

Comment: If you are using jquery, why are you still using `document.getElementById` and not jquery objects?

Comment: i am a newbie, so cud u help me in this ? i man how to use jquery variable

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-shadow` instead of `textShadow` ?

```
  $('.blue3d > textarea').css('text-shadow', horShadow.value+"px "+verShadow.value+"px "+blurShadow.value+"px "+'#'+colorshadow.color);
```

Comment: I just read it here that jquery uses camelcasing..[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923049/text-shadow-with-jquery)